# How to show custom taglist in window like :tag or :ptag

Tags: vim, tags, taglist

I use taglist() to get a tag list.
Then I did some filter, just leave some useful one like this:

```
let tttlist = taglist("^List$")
"echo ttt
let newtttlist = []
for item in tttlist
   if item['kind'] == 'i' || item['kind'] == 'c'
       call add(newtttlist, item)
   endif
endfor
echo newtttlist
```

But how to show them like :tag and :ptag in vim?

Answer (score 1):

I see no way to show tag***s*** using one of the commands you mentioned so solution is to use `:execute` with `:ptag`/`:tag` on the first item in the list:

```
execute 'ptag' fnameescape(get(newtttlist, 0, ''))
```

. More, you don’t need to process tags list after you have found one of the tags:

```
let tttlist = taglist("^List$")
for item in tttlist
   if item.kind == 'i' || item.kind == 'c'
       execute 'ptag' fnameescape(item.name)
   endif
endfor
```

. If you mean something else please post here how you are going to make `:ptag`/`:tag` show you a list of tags: according to the documentation and observed behavior all they do is jumping to the first match.

Also note: if key of the dictionary contains nothing more then latin letters, digits and underscores then you can access it as `dict.key` instead of `dict['key']`. When dictionary is used to pass structured data it is almost always true.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But it's not what I need.
Your way is just like call ":ptag List" directly. (I use 'List' as example).
I just want show tags which kind is 'i' or 'c'.

Comment: @stevenfrog You can use `echo`/`echom` to do this. Original request is “show like :tag/:ptag” and neither of these commands will show you anything more then one tag (:tag will jump to it, not show; :ptag will use preview window). Thus I can’t say what should be done as I do not know how they are supposed to be shown. Maybe you even need `echon`+`echohl` (you can’t emulate output of `:tselect` without them, for example).

Comment: If what you do want is showing like `tselect` you should consider using `:execute 'tselect /\V\^\%('.join(map(copy(newtttlist), 'escape(v:val, "\\")'), '\\|').'\)\$`.

Comment: ZyX:
I can not run your script correctly, just get a tag not found.

Comment: @stevenfrog Don’t know why, it works for me when I do 1. open help, 2. do `:let newtttlist=[':abc', ':iabc']`, 3. do `execute 'tselect /\V\^\%('.join(map(copy(newtttlist), 'escape(v:val, "\\")'), '\\|').'\)\$'`. Here I added missing `'` at the end, but there are no other changes between this command and command in previous comment. I should say though that with your code you have to use `'escape(v:val.name, "\\")'`: I have not mentioned that you add dictionaries to `newtttlist`, while my code expects names.

Comment: Neither of these problems will show “tag not found” error thus it is likely you’ve fixed them by yourself but have a problem elsewhere.

Comment: I know the problem. You misunderstand the format of newtttlist. The value should be like "{[name:List, kind:m, XXX],[name:List, kind:i, YYY]}"

Comment: @stevenfrog It should not throw “tag not found” error, it will throw “using dictionary as a string” instead. When writing any vim error message here do write either the first one or all, not the last.